# Unable to stop or remove a container in Docker, Permission denied is displayed

Tags: docker, containers

I have run several containers from an image in different ports, but I cant stop or remove these containers. I have run this command:

```
# sudo docker rm -f f85956145f61
```

And no message are displayed, however container is still displayed.

I have tried with  these commands:

```
# docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
# docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

But I get the following error:

```
# Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.15/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied
```

So, how can I remove all containers from my docker?

Comment: Do you have an alias for docker like `sudo docker` ? try again your command with `sudo docker ...` and let us know.

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to run docker commands if you are in the `docker` group.

Comment: Why did you not use `sudo` with the second set of commands? That should work.

Comment: Thank you user2915097, it works, using name instead of ID, but why is not possible to remove by ID, is it an docker issue?

Comment: It may have to do with Apparmor. Check dmesg for Apparmor errors. I have similar errors in Ubuntu 18 and downloaded Docker and I'm investigating how to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if you are trying to stop the container as root, but if not try to stop/kill the container as root or using sudo.

```
$ sudo docker kill $(docker ps -q)
$ sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

If this does not work try restarting docker service

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

and then try again to stop and delete the container. If it doesn't work you can try to kill the process(es) running inside the container from your host machine.

And to reference the container in `docker kill`, `docker stop`, `docker rm`,... and so on, you can either specify the container id or the container name, both are valid.

Comment: Doing just `sudo service docker restart` did the trick for me. I added some users to the docker group that might have made it mad... not sure thought.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this happening is that the daemon is busy committing the container.